# OCaml `Map.Make` input module

Tags: ocaml

I am following the example [here](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Map.html).

```
module IntPairs =
struct
  type t = int * int
  let compare (x0,y0) (x1,y1) =
    match Stdlib.compare x0 x1 with
    | 0 -> Stdlib.compare y0 y1
    | c -> c
end

module PairsMap = Map.Make(IntPairs)

let m = PairsMap.(
  empty 
  |> add (0,1) "hello" 
  |> add (1,0) "world"
)
```

My question is, why the code doesn't compile when I add `: Map.OrderedType` to the `module IntPairs` definition? Like this:

```
module IntPairs : Map.OrderedType =
struct
  type t = int * int
  let compare (x0,y0) (x1,y1) =
    match Stdlib.compare x0 x1 with
    | 0 -> Stdlib.compare y0 y1
    | c -> c
end

module PairsMap = Map.Make(IntPairs)

let m = PairsMap.(
  empty 
  |> add (0,1) "hello" 
  |> add (1,0) "world"
)
```

Error message:

```
64 | let m = PairsMap.(empty |> add (0, 1) "hello" |> add (1, 0) "world")
                                    ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b
       but an expression was expected of type 
       key
```

Isn't `IntPairs` expected to implement the module type `Map.OrderedType`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify the type `Map.OrderedType` you make the type of the key abstract. Instead, try the following and you'll find your code works.

```
module IntPairs : Map.OrderedType with type t = int * int =
struct
  type t = int * int
  let compare (x0,y0) (x1,y1) =
    match Stdlib.compare x0 x1 with
    | 0 -> Stdlib.compare y0 y1
    | c -> c
end
```

Or taking advantage of the fact that `Stdlib.compare` already works this way for tuples of ints.

```
module IntPairs : Map.OrderedType with type t = int * int =
struct
  type t = int * int
  let compare = Stdlib.compare
end
```

It may disambiguate the syntax here to add a set of parentheses.

```
module IntPairs : (Map.OrderedType with type t = int * int) =
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I understand it this way: `: Map.OrderedType` seals away the actual typing information `t = int * int`, so `Map.Make` cannot actually see the type of `Ord.t`. Thus when calling `add`, OCaml fails to recognize that `int * int` is the same as `key = Ord.t`?

Comment: @yyFred partly right. Ascribing a module type to the module does seal away the type equivalence. But the error does not happen during the `Map.Make(IntPairs)` call, as you can see from the compiler error message. It happens only later when you try to add an `int * int` value to the map. It's usually possible to avoid these issues by not ascribing a module type at all and just letting OCaml infer it. I.e. `module IntPairs = struct ... end`.